# How to disable "Save" until fields have passed validation. NO <form> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

On the client-side, I would like to somehow disable the "Save" button in case the validation has not passed. The solution is validating individual fields like so:

```
//checking if null

    $("#editAccountName").blur(function () {
            var editAccountName = $("#editAccountName").val();
            if (editAccountName == "" || editAccountName == null) {
                $("#editAccountNameError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The account name is required</font>');
                $("#editAccountName").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            }
            else {
                $("#editAccountNameError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
                $("#editAccountName").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
        });

//checking if null

        $("#editAddress").blur(function () {
            var editaddress = $("#editAddress").val();
            if (editaddress == "" || editaddress == null) {
                $("#editAddressError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The address is required</font>');
                $("#editAddress").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            }
            else {
                $("#editAddressError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
                $("#editAddress").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
        });

//checking if null

        $("#editCity").blur(function () {
            var editCity = $("#editCity").val();
            if (editCity == "" || editCity == null) {
                $("#editCityError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The city is required</font>');
                $("#editCity").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            }
            else {
                $("#editCityError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
                $("#editCity").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
        });

//checking if null  

        $("#editState").blur(function () {
            var editState = $("#editState").val();
            if (editState == "" || editState == null) {
                $("#editStateError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The city is required</font>');
                $("#editState").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            }
            else {
                $("#editStateError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
                $("#editState").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
        });

//no nulls or letters  

        $("#editZip").blur(function () {
            var regexnumbers = /\d+-?/;
            var editzip = $("#editZip").val();
            if (!regexnumbers.test(editzip) == true || editzip == '' || editzip == null) {
                $("#editZipError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The numeric zip code is required</font>');
                $("#editZip").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            }
            else {
                $("#editZipError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
                $("#editZip").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }
        });

//*optional* 
//needs to be exactly 10 digits in case anything is entered in any of the boxes

        $("#editArea,#editPrefix,#editSuffix").blur(function () {
            var phone = $("#editArea").val() + $("#editSuffix").val() + $("#editPrefix").val();

            if (phone.length > 0 && phone.length < 10) {
                $("#editPhoneError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The phone number must be 10 digits</font>');
                $("#editArea").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
                $("#editPrefix").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
                $("#editSuffix").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            }
            else {
                $("#editPhoneError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
                $("#editArea").css("background-color", "transparent");
                $("#editPrefix").css("background-color", "transparent");
                $("#editSuffix").css("background-color", "transparent");
            }

        });
```

I know this is not the cleanest solution but I can't make use of the Jquery plugin since that requires me to place the fields between `<form>` tags (which conflicts with other functionality). The markup looks like this:

```
<label>Clinic Name</label>
<input id="editAccountName" name="editAccountName" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.AccountName" /><span id="editAccountNameError" value="0"></span>

<label>Address</label>
<input id="editAddress" name="editAddress" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Address" /><span id="editAddressError" value="0"></span>

<label>City</label>
<input id="editCity" name="editCity" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.City" /><span id="editCityError" value="0"></span>

<label>State</label>
<input id="editState" name="editState" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.State" maxlength="2"/><span id="editStateError" value="0"></span>

<label>Zip</label>
<input id="editZip" name="editZip" maxlength="5" class="accountEdit" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.ZipCode" /><span id="editZipError" value="0"></span>

<label>Phone Number (optional)</label>
<div>
<input id="editArea" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editArea" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Area" depends />
</div>
<div>
<input id="editPrefix" maxlength="3" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editSuffix')" name="editPrefix" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Prefix" depends />
</div>
<div>
<input id="editSuffix" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tabout(this,'editPrefix')" name="editSuffix" style="float:left; width:70px;" type="text" value="@Model.Pharmacy.Suffix" depends />
                    </div>
<span style="margin-left:-208px; margin-top:50px;" id="editPhoneError" value="0"></span>
</div>

 <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
 <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, instead of setting the background-color on each field when it fails validation, I'd use a special css class - like "error" - that itself defines the look of each field. Then something like this:

```
        if (editaddress == "" || editaddress == null) {
            $("#editAddressError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The address is required</font>');
            $("#editAddress").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
        }
        else {
            $("#editAddressError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
            $("#editAddress").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
```

becomes this:

```
            if (editaddress == "" || editaddress == null) {
            $("#editAddressError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The address is required</font>');
            $("#editAddress").addClass("error");
        }
        else {
            $("#editAddressError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
            $("#editAddress").removeClass("error");
        }
```

(Note that I'd use something similar for the field error spans, but I'll eave that up to you)

Then, you could use the presence of that class ("error") at the end of your validation to enable/disable the save button:

```
$("#btnSave").prop("disabled", ($(":input.error").length > 0));
```

Basically, if there's at least one input field with the class "error", disable the save button. Otherwise, enable it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or one could also use `.toggleClass('error')` that way no `else` is needed

Comment: Right - I left the else there since we need it anyway for the error message span... But you are absolutely right, and if one uses css to toggle the error span's visibility, then the if/else is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little crazy, but in basic terms you could keep a boolean for each validation rule like so:

```
$("#editAccountName").blur(function () {
        var editAccountName = $("#editAccountName").val();
        if (editAccountName == "" || editAccountName == null) {
            $("#editAccountNameError").html('<font color="#cc0000">The account name is required</font>');
            $("#editAccountName").css("background-color", "#cc0000");
            accountNameValid = false;
        }
        else {
            $("#editAccountNameError").html('<font color="#cc0000"></font>');
            $("#editAccountName").css("background-color", "transparent");
            accountNameValid = true;
        }
    });
```

And later check if the button should be clickable:

```
if(accountNameValid && addressValid && ...){
    // process form
}
```